# Input: URL Output: All Words on the Website

Tags: javascript, html, screen-scraping

so im trying to build a webpage where i have a input field for a url and it would then calculate the words on that webpage. I tried so far with a framework called scraper.js which is node based, i made it so far that i get literally every word from the page, including HTML tags and code. Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: You'd **have** to look at the DOM, which would include all of those tags. Your only option is to strip the tags out, extracting the relevant content that you're looking for. You'd also have to make sure you scraped the content legally, without infringing on copyright.

Comment: It should be totally automated, so do you think i should create a expression with all tags and exclude these from the data? copyright shouldnt be a problem since its only for my personal use.

Comment: If you just need to strip the tags, then do that.